# Unable to create the messaging service without a project ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, laravel-8, php-7.2

While sending push notification facing this error, It's working fine in laravel 6 but after upgrade laravel to 8 facing this error.

> Unable to create the messaging service without a project ID

**Below composer version we used.**

```
"php": "^7.2|^8.0",
"fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
"laravel-notification-channels/fcm": "2.7.0",
"laravel/framework": "^8.75",
```

**Below code for sending push notification**

```
$fcmNotification = FcmNotification::create()
      ->setTitle($this->notification->title)
      ->setBody(strip_tags($this->notification->message));

$sendData = [
   'action' => 'deep-link',
   'key'    => $this->key,
];

// The FcmMessage contains other options for the notification
return FcmMessage::create()
   ->setCondition(self::PRIORITY_HIGH)
   ->setNotification($fcmNotification)
   >setData($sendData);
```